# Can't find Pipeline Wizard in Azure DevOps Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I inherited a project a while back that uses Azure DevOps Pipelines for deployment and when I want to edit the pipeline I have access to a wizard to walk through the tasks, triggers, variables, options, etc..  I then set up a completely separate project for a different organization and when I go to create a new pipelines it's only allowing me to use a YAML script. I don't see a way to run through the wizard.

Also, in the previous project under Pipelines I have sub menus for Pipelines and Environments.  In the project I just set up I don't have these choices, only Builds.  So it seems like I may be using an older version in the original project, I'm not sure and I can't seem to find a way to change the version.

Is this wizard no longer available for new projects?  Is there a setting somewhere or something I am missing to gain access to it or do I have to use YAML only from this point on?  If that is the case, is there a way to upgrade the old project to this version (I want to stay consistent)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this wizard no longer available for new projects?

No, you just facing the different design of azure devops.

- *You can only create the YAML*.

The page you can see the `tasks`, `triggers` or other tabs is the design of **Classic editor** pipeline.

Please choose **Use the classic editor** after you new pipeline.

[image]

Click **Continue** after select the source (the repository and the branch) for your project.

At the next step, you can choose Empty job, also you can add some tasks.

[image]

Note: do not select **Configure as code**. It is YAML.

Now, you can see the tabs like `tasks`, `variables`, `triggers` and etc.

---

- *Could not seen **Pipelines** and **Environments**.*

These two tabs are the new UI design which published in recent sprints. And we provide it by enable **Multi-stage pipelines** in
   **Preview features** panel.

I assume you did not enable this feature and just saw **Builds** there.

Click your head account which located in right corner, then choose **Preview features**:

[image]

Then enable **Multi-stage pipelines**.

[image]

After enable it and close the panel, this page will be re-load automatically. Then you will see **Pipelines** and **Environments** in the left wizard panel.